# How to get URL parameters with Javascript - CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The page open a popup with webresource. I pass parameters for URL, and i need to get them usign javascript. 
There is the code:

```
function open() {
   var dataItemValue = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
   Xrm.Utility.openWebResource("xpto_/ShowDataParams.htm", dataItemValue, 300,300);    
}
```

The `console.log(parameters)` is working. At the other function i need to acess the `parameters`. 
Thank's.

Comment: I'm a bit lost - you've got the parameters in JavaScript already.  If you mean you want access to the parameter object outside that function then just declare it and populate it outside the function so it has global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The point is parameters will not be available. The right way to pass parameters to form is to pass it through url:

```
var addParams = "Param1=" + param1 + "&Param2=" + param2;
var webresourceurl = "/webresources/new_/webresource.htm?Data=" + encodeURIComponent(addParams);
```

Detailed explanations are available in this article - http://butenko.pro/2014/06/dynamics-crm-2013-step-by-step-creating-dialog-windows/

Comment: my webresource is : `/WebResources/xpto_/html/UploadFile?preview=1`. So i put: ` var currentRecId = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();` , `var addParams = "recordid=" + currentRecId;` and `var src = "/WebResources/xpto_/html/UploadFile?preview=1?Data=" + encodeURIComponent(addParams);` . And put the variable url in openDialog. But it still doesn´t work.

Comment: You should start from var src = "/WebResources/xpto_/html/UploadFile?preview‌​=1&Data=" +

Comment: Hi, Thank's. I already do the code. I edit the question with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've saw some cases when sending `GET` parameters to custom WebResources is not working properly. Somehow it could mess with internal URL rewriting in CRM core.

Normally it shows as error `500` instead of your expected web content. And the reason is, as I mentioned, your `GET` parameters messes with standard CRM URL rewriting mechanism. When you add custom parameters, URL no longer matches rewrite rules and CRM explodes with error `500`.

In this case you can use `hash-bang` strings. They could be passed to URL, but prepended with `#!` symbols. This trick makes them invisible for server-side operations, since everything after `#` symbol in URL is supposed refer to anchors (local links) within the page, and that's why it is skipped by normal server-side code.

But you can decode it on client side.

For example, your URL could look like following:

```
xpto_/ShowDataParams.htm#!name1=value1&name2=value2
```

And you can use following function to get name-value pairs from your URL inside your web resource:

```
function ExtractParameters() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var pairs = {};
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('#!') + 2).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        var hash = hashes[i].split('=');

        if(hash.length > 1) {
            pairs[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        } else {
            pairs[hash[0]] = null;
        }   
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

Side note: it's not necessary to use `#!` the `#` is important, but I'm prefer to have more complex combination of symbols for verbose purpose, so it won't mix with anything else.